# why can't I create a new gnome terminal profile or edit one?

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I create a new gnome profile, it isn't saved when I hit close. When I create a new gnome profile, I can't edit the preferences to change things like the colour, font, etc., either. I also can't change the default ones in the same way. All the options are greyed out. Would anyone know why this would be?

Comment: What are the outputs of `ls -l ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal` and `ls -l ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles` commands?

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is that you lost permissions of your own files. This could be easily solved with chmod/chown:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.gconf/apps/
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/dconf
chmod -R u+w ~/.gconf/apps/
chmod -R u+w ~/.config/dconf
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest (at the moment of writing this answer) gnome-terminal settings storage is dconf. The terminal requires [gsettings-backend-dconf](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/dconf-gsettings-backend) package. However, sometimes (maybe on other distributions) the terminal installs without this dependency. When it happens, gnome-terminal works and opens but it does not retain any new profiles and changes in the existing profile.

Below are the steps that resolved this problem for me:

1. Install dconf-gsettings-backend package

   ```
   sudo apt install dconf-gsettings-backend
   ```

   After this step I could see that `~/.config/dconf/user` file was created.
2. Reboot
3. Try to edit or add a new profile